# Button click adds php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add a new form when clicking a button. I have the code working with regular text (e.g. 'abc') but it doesn't work when I do a php include.

Any ideas what the issue may be?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".inputs"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_input"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<?php include "http://localhost:8888/abcde.php"; ?>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inputs">
    <button class="add_input">Add Input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Emmm you can't include php code with html :S ... Backend != frontend...if you want to include PHP code, then, do an Ajax to "abcde.php"....

Comment: `wrapper.load("http://localhost:8888/abcde.php");` OR if you MUST: `wrapper.append(\`<?php include "http://localhost:8888/abcde.php"; ?>\`);` - but also make sure that wrapper is available in the click event

Comment: In your example, there is no class or ID called "wrapper"

Comment: @kawnah `var wrapper         = $(".inputs");`

Comment: Is file that does the PHP include a PHP file? If not you will have to change your approach. AJAX seems to be an appropriate fit here.

Answer (score 0):

As i know jquery function append() is for appending some thing to an html element. But you are trying to append your php element to an array. I do not think it is true. You can look this:
[jquery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

For add some thing to an array you can use js function push()

```
anArray.push(something);
```